# Best way to practise Datalog?

Tags: prolog, logic, datalog, pydatalog

What is the best way to practice Datalog?

Should I practice in pyDatalog? Or should I go with Prolog? (but isnt the syntax different for Datalog and Prolog?)

Thank you.

Comment: See [DES](https://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/fernan/DES/). It's written in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: I am trying to run des_acide.jar for installing DES. Its not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "practicing Datalog". If you mean that you are looking for a program/implementation/engine that can interpret your Datalog logic programs and execute queries over them, you may want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog. It has a list of implementations.

As Datalog is a subset of Prolog, any Prolog implementations are likely overkill. You may want to give implementations like DLV a try. DLV (search from "DLV Datalog") supports the Datalog language and allows extensions with negation and disjunction via the answer set semantics. Another very lightweight implementation of pure Datalog is Eunomia (search for "Eunomia Datalog").

I have no experience with pyDatalog so I can't speak to that.